# How to multiple c# form entries into one excel document?

Tags: c#, excel

I have some code which stores the value of my form into an excel spreadsheet, however, when a second person's details are entered and the form exported, a new spreadsheet is created, whereas I want to add a second line to the existing spreadsheet. I can work out how to make it go to a second line, but how do I stop it from opening a new spreadsheet?

The code is:

```
if (RunOnce)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application { };
        };

        #region Validation

        int years = DateTime.Now.Year - DateOfBirthPicker.Value.Year;
        if (DateOfBirthPicker.Value.AddYears(years) > DateTime.Now) years--;


        if (years < 18 || years > 21  )
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("You must be over 18 and under 21 to apply for the Elite University");
        }


        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TitleComboBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a title");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstNameTextBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a First Name");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastNameTextBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a last name");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DateOfBirthPicker.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a date of birth");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SexComboBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please select your sex");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HouseNumberTextBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a house number");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StreetNameTextBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a street name");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TownTextBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a town");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CountyTextBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a county");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PostCodeTextBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a postcode");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EmailAddressTextBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address");
        }

       // if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ALevelPassesTextBox.Text))
       // {
        //    Error = true;
         //   MessageBox.Show("Please enter the number of A-Level Passes");
      //  }
       // else
        //{
       //     int ALevelPasses = Convert.ToInt32(ALevelPassesTextBox.Text);
       // }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Subject1TextBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your first subject choice");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Subject2TextBox.Text))
        {
            Error = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your second subject choice");
        }


      //  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DonationAmountTextBox.Text))
       // {
       //     Error = true;
       //     MessageBox.Show("Please enter your donation ammount");
       // }
       // else
       // {
       //     int DonationAmount = Convert.ToInt32(DonationAmountTextBox.Text);
        //}

      //  if (ALevelPasses < 3)
       // {
       //     Error = true;
       //     MessageBox.Show("You must have a minimum of 3 A-level passes to apply for the Elite University");
       // }

       // if (DonationAmount< 10)
       // {
        //    Error = true;
        //    MessageBox.Show("You must donate more than £10");
        //}
        #endregion

        if (!Error & RunOnce)
        {

            Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

            xla.Visible = true;

            ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Title";
            ws.Cells[1, 2] = "First Name";
            ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Last Name";
            ws.Cells[1, 4] = "Date of birth ";
            ws.Cells[1, 5] = "Sex";
            ws.Cells[1, 6] = "House Number ";
            ws.Cells[1, 7] = "Street Name";
            ws.Cells[1, 8] = "Town";
            ws.Cells[1, 9] = "County";
            ws.Cells[1, 10] = "PostCode";
            ws.Cells[1, 11] = "Email Address";
            ws.Cells[1, 12] = "Number of A-Level Passes";
            ws.Cells[1, 13] = "Subject1";
            ws.Cells[1, 14] = "Subject2";
            ws.Cells[1, 15] = "Subject3";


            ws.Cells[2, 1] = TitleComboBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 2] = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 3] = LastNameTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 4] = DateOfBirthPicker.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 5] = SexComboBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 6] = HouseNumberTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 7] = StreetNameTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 8] = TownTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 9] = CountyTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 10] = PostcodeLabel.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 11] = EmailAddressTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 12] = ALevelPassesTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 13] = Subject1TextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 14] = Subject2TextBox.Text;
            RunOnce = true;

        }

        if (!RunOnce)
        {

            Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

            xla.Visible = true;

            ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Title";
            ws.Cells[1, 2] = "First Name";
            ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Last Name";
            ws.Cells[1, 4] = "Date of birth ";
            ws.Cells[1, 5] = "Sex";
            ws.Cells[1, 6] = "House Number ";
            ws.Cells[1, 7] = "Street Name";
            ws.Cells[1, 8] = "Town";
            ws.Cells[1, 9] = "County";
            ws.Cells[1, 10] = "PostCode";
            ws.Cells[1, 11] = "Email Address";
            ws.Cells[1, 12] = "Number of A-Level Passes";
            ws.Cells[1, 13] = "Subject1";
            ws.Cells[1, 14] = "Subject2";
            ws.Cells[1, 15] = "Subject3";


            ws.Cells[2, 1] = TitleComboBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 2] = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 3] = LastNameTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 4] = DateOfBirthPicker.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 5] = SexComboBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 6] = HouseNumberTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 7] = StreetNameTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 8] = TownTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 9] = CountyTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 10] = PostcodeLabel.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 11] = EmailAddressTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 12] = ALevelPassesTextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 13] = Subject1TextBox.Text;
            ws.Cells[2, 14] = Subject2TextBox.Text;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Need more code - the above just creates a new spreadsheet and populates the first 2 rows. Where's the code to add to that spreadsheet object?

Comment: Ah that's what i'm looking to do. I can get it to open and add the first two rows, but I don't know how to add to the spreadsheet :)

Comment: I can't seem to get it to add to the existing sheet, only create a new one, as trying to split the code to open up the excel document simply results in the code saying that it is out of scope.

Comment: I have now updated the code to show where I have tried to condition when the new spreadsheet is created, I keep getting an error saying xla cannot be declared in this scope because the name is used in an encoding local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: You're calling "xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet)" in both cases - that code will add a new workbook. If you want to open an existing workbook, you need to open it by the filename.

Comment: Ah that makes sense thank you

Comment: How would I open the spreadsheet that has just opened then? I'm a bit confused by that :(